# jQuery.grep() match URL both www and non www, http/https

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jquery to search a json string for the matched url and then fetch all the data inside that object.

I fetch the url with

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

However this returns

http://somesite.com/

inside the json string could be any of the following

- http://somesite.com/
- http://somesite.com
- http://www.somesite.com/
- http://www.somesite.com https://somesite.com/

etc etc.

My code is to match the url and then do something.  How would I go about using jQuery.grep() to take the different style urls in the query?  Below is my code so far.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var json = exampleJsonString;
var js = JSON.parse(json);
var result = $.grep(js, function(e){ return e.url == url; });

if (result.length == 0) {
  // not found :(
  console.log('Not found');
} else if (result.length == 1) {
  // Result matched
  console.log(result);

} 

else {
  // multiple items found
  console.log('multiple items found');
  console.log(result); 
}
```

What I want to do is check for somesite.com using jquery grep.  As in this line it checks if the string is equal.

```
var result = $.grep(js, function(e){ return e.url == url; });
```

Comment: You could remove `http:// `, `www.` and `.com`from both and then compare. If Domain name matching is what you are interested in

Comment: Well first of all of course nothing stops you to check against several different values in your grep filter callback function. But maybe you want to start with location.hostname instead of the complete href(?) - that could make matching easier. (If that will work of course depends on what specific results you need, which you said nothing about.)

Comment: Well the issue is that the grep searches the json string for the url.  If it doesn't match then it wont do the rest.  So with $.grep(js, function(e){ return e.url == url; });  will match that exact url, even a trailing / will force it to say not found.  I know how to regex a url but what I want to regex is probably just the somesite.com part.  But I am not sure how to tell jQuery.grep()

Comment: I'm confused - if you know how to use a regex with grouping, and it does what you need, why are you trying to wedge it into $.grep?   Just use the regex?   It also looks like you're doing more with the url than just matching the hostname

Comment: Because the $.grep fetches back the json data in the object based on the value in one key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grep function to filter the records. Here in your case want to check different URL's in the object like 'http://somesite.com/','http://somesite.com' etc, mention all the URL's that you want to consider in grep function. Here is the sample code.

```
   var varObj = jQuery.grep(dataobject, function (a) {
            if (a.url == "http://somesite.com/" || a.url == "http://somesite.com" || a.url == "http://www.somesite.com/")
                return true;
        });
```

Comment: Thankyou, that seems to be the one.  I was hoping for some function in jquery grep to deal with urls but this is the next best thing :)

Comment: You could put the javascript reg ex inside the grep callback rather than use `==`.